# Would AppArmor protect against a bug like Heartbleed?

Tags: apparmor

Is it capable of "containing"/preventing the exploitation of things such as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think AppArmor would help. Heartbleed is a bug within openssl, it allows to read out memory allocated to the process. It has nothing to do with rights escalation or similar.

Comment: Just to be clear so I understand: Heartbleed allows access to the memory of the process which _utilizes_ OpenSSL? Not system-wide memory?

Comment: Your question was not very specific. I assumed you worried about leaking private keys through the OpenSSL-using application. Heartbleed might leak more memory outside the application, and that might be prevented through OS-layer countermeasures like AppArmor. Don't quote me on that though ;)